# finding factors using C on GCC compiler

Tags: c, gcc

I wrote this function to find factors of an int,
When I compile using GCC I get a warning saying "conflicting types for 'factors' "

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



main(){
    factors(18);
}

void factors(int x){
  int i = 1;
  while (i<=x){
    if (i%x == 0)
       printf("%d \t", i);
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Add the declaration of `factors` before `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main()` has to have a return type and the default is `int` so change that and don't forget the return statement at the end.

Also you have to put a function prototype before main, so if you compile and call the function it is known. Or you would have to put the function declaration before main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*function prototype*/
void factors(int x);

int main() {
//^ return type 

    factors(18);

    return 0;
  //^^^^^^^^^ return to end the program 'nicely'

}

void factors(int x) {

    int i = 1;

    while (i <= x) {
        if (i % x == 0)
            printf("%d \t", i);

        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```